# What is stolen money called?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a question about money.

We have different sorts of money such as blood money and I was wondering what stolen money is called.

Is there any kind of specific word for this type of money?

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin - I don’t think it is a duplicate, the older question asked about “money ***earned*** illegally, here is specifically about ***stolen*** money.

Comment: The question includes stolen money: "Money that is earned through bad sources like corrupted politics, corrupted business, ransom money, **stolen or theft money**." The answers so far repeat answers in that thread (booty, loot).

Comment: Yes @TaliesinMerlin That is certainly true. But how was the OP going to find that in Search? It is buried in a body of text that might put off the new user.

Comment: I honestly don't know, Cascabel. I only observe that a similar question exists. I don't blame the OP for not initially finding it.

Comment: Yes @TaliesinMerlin...that is certainly a good point. We have had a few questions like this in which it is difficult to reverse search. How can we resolve this?

Comment: That would be duplicate if you can say a bank robber earns his money by robbing banks.

Answer (score 4):

**loot** (n)

> 1.1) Stolen money or valuables.
>
> "The gang escaped with their loot"

[-Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/loot)

An example I saw was from [Unsolved Texas Mysteries](https://books.google.com.gt/books?id=JNPNeZC66YkC&pg=PA132&dq=%22bury%20the%20loot%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLsJ7F3K3jAhVnzlkKHeRLCUIQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22bury%20the%20loot%22&f=false) (Wallace O Chariton)

> ...having so much money..one of them presented the prudent thing to do would be to bury ***the loot...***

[image]

Another thing to take under consideration is that *money* is a fairly recent concept. Originally the "coin of the realm" was minted in copper, silver, and gold. Paper money, while invented centuries ago in China, was not used in the western world until only in the last 400 years.

---

I have also seen this used by Calvin to describe his take at Christmas.

[image]

Although this probably destroys my case, I could not resist posting a Calvin & Hobbes strip by the famous Bill Watterson.

Comment: _Loot_ (and _booty_) to me very strongly implies something that requires effort to carry, and also something you’ve obtained through difficulty and at some risk to yourself. If you rob a bank and escape with a bag full of bank notes, yes, that’s your loot; but if you steal a £50 note from your nan’s purse lying on the table, I would find it very odd to describe that as your ‘loot’.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Have you ever calculated the weight of a miilion dollares in $100 bills? It is like 10 kg.  Maybe it depends on the quantity/weight. That's how the narcos do it.

Comment: I have no, no – I limited myself to thinking of the Dalton Brothers or some such, running down the street with heavy bags of money on their backs. How many bazillion dollars they’d actually have to steal for that scenario to be realistic, I didn’t pause to consider.

Comment: “Vote to Close addiction”  hits again!!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use ***[booty:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/booty)***

> [ U ] any valuable things or money stolen by an army at war or by thieves.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Answer (score 2):

I like [swag](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/swag) myself
Dictionary.com
noun
Slang.

```
plunder; booty.
money; valuables.
```

If you put **loot** into a thesaurus you'll find more synonyms.

Comment: I have usually seen _swag_ used to describe stolen articles of value such as silver and gold items, like the candlesticks stolen by Jean Valjean in _Les Miserables._

Comment: Sorry if it appears I robbed you of _loot_, but it was already the thought I had .

Comment: Good answer, but worth noting that swag also refers to the near-worthless promotional trinkets handed by companies/institutions out at conferences and conventions. Swag could refer to something very valuable, or to a crappy piece of junk.

Comment: @NuclearWang That's a new meaning of swag, based on the primary one given in the answer.

Comment: @Cascabel Robbed the loot indeed :-). (But I bagged the swag.)